# trigger working issue in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have an issue with my mysql database trigger. I have a table in my database which has two field 'created date' and 'last updated date'. I am using 'TimeStamp' datatype for 'created date' and 'date' datatype for 'last updated date'.

I made a trigger which is used for updating date in 'last updated date' field.
My trigger code is here

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` AFTER Insert ON `table1`
      FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
         update table1 set last_updated_date = NOW()
          where id = (select top id from table1)
END;
```

I have no idea where I am wrong. please suggest me to resolve this problem.

Please frenkly ask if any issue to understand.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an invalid sql syntax in sub query. use **LIMIT** instead **TOP**

The **TOP** clause works on MSSQL server.

Execute the below query it will work.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` BEFORE INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.last_updated_date = NOW(); 
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You exucute this query now, I have executed myself its working fine. here I thought you want to update last_updated_date is current time either before or after insert table1 particular record so I have modified like that .

Comment: Execute the above query ,just you change table name and field name . It will work. I have executede the above again ,its working fine. Still you are facing issue just send me the error

Comment: it gives the error for 'new' keyword for field name.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name`
AFTER INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

update table1 set last_updated_date = NOW()
      where id = (select top id from table1)


END;//
```